# Referencing a variable inside another module/.py file

Tags: python, list, pygame

So here's my dilemma, I have two integers in one .py file (do you call em modules, I'm not sure) and in another .py file I have a for loop that has those varialbes referencing to it. Do I have to state each variable in each of the .py files I have or can I sorta use global or something else?

\main.py

from rabbits import Rabbit

```
WINDOW_WIDTH = 640
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400
```

\rabbits.py

```
class Rabbit(object):

rabbitCounter = 0
    NEW_RABBIT = 40
    RABBIT_SIZE = 64

    rabbits = []
    for i in range (20):
        rabbits.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOW_WIDTH
        - RABBIT_SIZE), random.randint (0, WINDOW_HEIGHT - RABBIT_SIZE),
        RABBIT_SIZE, RABBIT_SIZE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In file a.py:

```
var1 = 42
var2 = 43
```

In file b.py

```
import a

print (a.var1)
print (a.var2)
```

Comment: So I need to import them?

Comment: Yes, import the module and use the dot notation to use then